# filebeat yaml use the current filename in index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

```
paths:
 - /var/log/*.log
```

I am using this as the path in `filebeat` for shipping logs.
The output is elasticsearch.

```
output:
    elasticsearch:
        index: filebeat
```

The logs are already formatted in JSON, I just want index to reflect where the logs come from. In my scenario, anyone may put a file `abcd.log` in the logs folder. I want these logs to be sent to index `filebeat-abcd-19.05.2016` or something like that. Since the logs are preformatted, we don't want any logstash in between. Currently they go in `filebeat-dd.mm.yyyy` format. Basically I want to include filename in between. How do I do that without logstash?

Comment: And why do you add the logstash tag if you don't want to use it?

Comment: From the documentation, it does not look like it's possible

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this use-case:
filebeat (multiple prospectors)->logstash (multiple filter)->elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am already aware of that, and as a last resort i will have no choice but to put logstash in between, It would be far more straight forward for me without it though, if there was some way. Plus it saves the cost of the logstash node (it needs to be a separate node if implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Just today solved this with Ingest Pipeline. Need to chain processors into something like that:

```
{
  "grok": {
    "field": "_source.source",
    "patterns": [
      "/%{NOSLASH:index_name}.log"
    ],
    "pattern_definitions": {
      "NOSLASH": "[^/]+"
    }
  }
  }
},
{
  "date": {
    "field": "_source.@timestamp",
    "target_field": "index_date",
    "formats": [
      "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    ],
    "timezone": "your timezone if needed"
  }
},
{
  "gsub": {
    "field": "index_date",
    "pattern": "T.*",
    "replacement": ""
   }
},
{
  "set": {
    "field": "_index",
    "value": "filebeat-{{index_name}}-{{index_date}}"
  }
}
```

First, grok filename from source path, then copy date with formatting, then trim time from date with gsub, then set index name.

You then may choose to remove fields `index_name` and `index_date`.

Also in `output` section of `filebeat.yml` you'll need to point output to `pipeline` instead of `index`.